# PHP recursive delete function gives warning message

Tags: php, warnings, delete-file, unlink

My function cleanup looks like that.

```
function cleanUp($exdirs, $exfiles){
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.'), 
  RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);
foreach($it as $entry) {
  if ($entry->isDir() && !in_array($entry->getBasename(), $exdirs)) {
    try {
      rmdir($entry->getPathname());
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
      // dir not empty
    }
  }
  elseif (!in_array($entry->getFileName(), $exfiles)) {
    unlink($entry->getPathname());
  }
}
}
```

And calling this function like that

```
$excludeDirsNames = array('cgi-bin');
$excludeFileNames = array('ws.zip');
cleanUp($excludeDirsNames , $excludeFileNames);
```

Now the problem is i'm getting warning message. `can not unlink cgi-bin on line unlink($entry->getPathname());`

What's wrong with my function? How to fix that problem?

Comment: Have you checked permissions on that directory?

Comment: which one? cgi-bin is exclusion. I'm sending exclusions array to function

Comment: please read your warning message once again: `can not unlink cgi-bin on line`. It is clear for me that you're trying to delete `cgi-bin` directory and you have no enough permissions for it.

Comment: it is not necessary to read the function, the warning message states clearly that you're trying to delete it. And you can disclaim this, but php doesn't lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that `cgi-bin` is a symlink and not a regular directory. That's why it's getting into the "unlink" section. The error message is probably due to permissions.

The fix, move 'cgi-bin' to the $excludeFileNames array.